# How to interpret the nested function calls using macros in C

Tags: c, function, macros, header

I came across macro definition like below. Is the definition of the macro RVS_E(_I, _E) valid?
And how does the macro RVS_C() work (as it is dependent on RVS_E) and what would be the output of RVS_C

```
extern unsigned int rvs_trace_port;

/* Instrumentation point */
void RVS_Ipoint(unsigned int); 

/* Instrumentation macros and functions */
#define RVS_I(_I)     (rvs_trace_port = (_I))
#define RVS_E(_I,_E)  ((void)RVS_I((_I)),(_E))
#define RVS_C(_I,_C)  (RVS_E(_I,0)?(_C):(_C))
#define RVS_T(_I)     RVS_E((_I),1)
#define RVS_F(_I)     RVS_E((_I),0)

unsigned int RVS_CM (unsigned int * k, unsigned int pos, unsigned int b);
unsigned int RVS_DM (unsigned int id, unsigned int * k, unsigned int b);
#define RVS_DML RVS_DM
```

Following is the example code where these macros are used (it is an autogenerated "instrumented" code and hence looks a bit crazy)

```
if ( ( rvs_tmp_k_362=0,  RVS_DM(362,&rvs_tmp_k_362,(unsigned int)(RVS_CM(&rvs_tmp_k_362,2,(unsigned int)((nvHist_Queue.DataPtr != (uint8*)&nvHist_QData)))
{
 .....
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/cCa23o

Comment: I don't see any of these macros in the expression below. It's just calling extern functions `RVS_DM` and `RVS_CM`, but unnecessarily using the comma operator to create confusion and greater chance of bugs. Is this code already expanded (preprocessed) code, perhaps?

Comment: This is the way to get frustrated and eventually commit the suicide.

Comment: just to clarify - I know this code is horrible. But it is autocreated by a tool and I am trying to identify a bug. There are other conditions down the line that use the RVS_E RVS_I macros. Just shown the "if" for example